# jquery event fires twice

Tags: jquery

I have a select element from which the users can select a value and copy it to a textarea element. Everything works as expected with the exception that the value from the select element is copied twice.

```
$('#cp_objs_for_goal_button').mouseup(function(){
    if ($("#cp_objs_for_goal_select").attr("selectedIndex") != 0)
    {
        console.log('selected index: '+$("#cp_objs_for_goal_select").attr("selectedIndex"));
        curr_txt = $('#pop_goal_text').val();
        console.log('curr_txt: '+curr_txt);
        added_txt = $('#cp_objs_for_goal_select option:selected').text();
        console.log('added_txt: '+added_txt);
        if (curr_txt)
        {
            new_pop_text = curr_txt + ' ' + added_txt;
        }
        else
        {
            new_pop_text = added_txt;
        }
        console.log('new_pop_text: '+new_pop_text);
        $('#pop_goal_text').val(new_pop_text);

        // TODO - This throws error:
        // $('#cp_objs_for_goal_select option').get(0).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
})
```

When I click the cp_objs_for_goal_button button, I get this.... from the console log:

```
selected index: 1
curr_txt:
added_txt: Restore geomorphic integrity
new_pop_text: Restore geomorphic integrity

selected index: 1
curr_txt: Restore geomorphic integrity
added_txt: Restore geomorphic integrity
new_pop_text: Restore geomorphic integrity Restore geomorphic integrity
```

Here the html:

```
<select id="cp_objs_for_goal_select" style="width:100%"> 
    <option>Select the Objective you would like to copy to this project:</option> 
    <option>Restore geomorphic integrity</option> 
</select> 
<div id="cp_objs_for_goal_button" class="awesome" style="border:0;">Copy</div>
```

Comment: Can I see the page this is on?  I've had such things happen when jQuery itself was loading twice.

Comment: Why do you use "mouseup" and not "click"?

Comment: rob - this page is still in development. It isn't live yet. But I will check to see that I don't load jquery twice.

Comment: There is a ":selected" pseudo-selector, that might simplify your code a little bit: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: Tim, I am using mouseup because when I used click, the same thing happens.

Comment: @Eric - Can you post the HTML around the `#cp_objs_for_goal_button` element? This sort of thing often happens if an event handler is assigned to the event of a parent, and again to a child. For example, see this fiddle (click anywhere, get 1 alert, click the link, get 2): http://jsfiddle.net/QLVhr/

Comment: James, I've added the HTML to the original post.

Comment: Tim, the code was more compact but when this error occurred, I've broken things down to see where I was going wrong. I'll clean up again after this problem is solved. :-)

Comment: @Eric - I think your problem lies elsewhere... it seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/QLVhr/2/

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out to be an event propagation issue. I was using event delegation and the parent selector class existed twice in the chain of propagation, so it was firing twice. but once I removed the parent selector class so only one remain in my entire page, it went back to normal and only fired once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've confirmed too, in isolation, the script works as intended. However, the page has tons of moving parts and I couldn't isolate the problem. So, I removed the jquery even listener and added an on onclick to the button that calls the method. This works fine.

Thanks for all input.

Comment: If i need to add the event using J query depending on a case. what could I do?

Answer (score 5):

This is a common Bug in Jquery. you can find many articles around internet specially on SO for event being fired twice. You can try this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#task-list li', function(e)
 {
       alert('Hellow world');
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
 });
```

And it's definitely Javascript problem because if you hit google and search for **event fire twice** you will see that Angular, Jquery and backbone etc all are somewhere firing events twice or even thrice. So, it's seem that it's javascript behind this.

Answer (score 1):

Check javascript event bubbling, here is the first link i found http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1751-jQuery-Live-Method-And-Event-Bubbling.htm

usually event.preventDefault() helps me

Answer (score 0):

Very little information to work on, but if I have to make a wild guess, check the following:

Double check that you don't have similar ID's on your page.

(Make sure your form doesn't have the same ID.)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I already checked that. And, there are no double ids.

Comment: Also, check there there were no 2 different event handlers.

Comment: Check my link. http://jsfiddle.net/NdKBu/ . I replaced console log with alert...and alert fires only once. It must be something else on your page.

Comment: If you can, try to supply us with a basic example on jsfiddle where your problem occurred. (I know the page is still under-development)

Comment: Marc, I am going to try to copy out all the html and js to a separate file and see where I get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `event.stopPropagation()` resolved this problem for me.

Using the above code as an example:

```
$('#cp_objs_for_goal_button').mouseup(function(event){
   //handler code...
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note that the jQuery event parameter was added to the handler function.